# Covert html date value to RFC 2822

Tags: php

I have following code,

```
$date = $_POST["s-date"]; // get from  form. value pass correctly. 
 $time =  "".$hour.":".$minute.":".$second.""; // ok
   echo RFC2822($date,$time);   

function RFC2822($date,$time = '00:00') { 
   $array =  list($d, $m, $y) = explode('-', $date); 
    list($h, $i, $s) = explode(':', $time);

    return date('r', mktime($h,$i,0,$m,$d,$y));
}
```

When I execute this script, time fragment is printed correctly, But date is displayed as Jul 08 2025 always even passing different date to the function. How to fix this.

Comment: What can be the value of `$_POST["s-date"]` ?

Comment: its like 2016-01-20 gain from  html date type input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must need to check the value of this input `$_POST["s-date"]` it must be follow this format of date:

```
`DD-MM-YY`
```

because, you are creating list in this format (DD-MM-YY):

```
$array =  list($d, $m, $y) = explode('-', $date);
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

As you mentioned, you are using HTML date and HTML date format is 
`'YYYY-MM-DD'`, now just change the list variable order as per date format.

Comment: @ChandimalHarischandra: just change the order of list variable.. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather your problem lies not with the code you've shared, but somewhere else. If I copy-paste your script and put in a fixed date on $date, it works as expected. (I've removed $time for missing vars)

```
$date = "27-02-2014";
echo RFC2822($date);   

function RFC2822($date,$time = '00:00:00') {
   $array =  list($d, $m, $y) = explode('-', $date);
    list($h, $i, $s) = explode(':', $time);

    return date('r', mktime($h,$i,0,$m,$d,$y));
}
```

Outputs

```
Thu, 27 Feb 2014 12:00:00 +0100
```

From this I expect that your `$_POST['s-date']` var somehow gets a fixed 08-07-2025 or some other input that will make it 08 Jul 2025.

Comment: No it passes date correctly. ( different dates) and pass inside function correctly. Its like 2016-01-20. Gain from date type html input

Comment: well if it's 2016-01-20 then there's your problem. Your function obviously expects it to be d-m-y. If you're sending y-m-d you should change this line:

`$array =  list($d, $m, $y) = explode('-', $date);`

to 

`$array =  list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $date);`